# How can I get the level 1 and 2 residual variances from a lmer model in R?

Tags: r, lme4, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to fill out a results table for my masters thesis in psychology but have been unable to compute the values that I need.
I have conducted a daily diary study with data nested in days (level 1) and person (level 2). My multilevel model using lmer works great.

For reference:

```r
model.random2 <- lmer(Arbeitsziele ~ 1 + Bildung.II.cwc +
    group + Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit.cwc + 
    (1 + Bildung.II + Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit | SERIAL), 
    data = Daten)
```

Using `summary()` I get the following results table:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Arbeitsziele ~ 1 + Bildung.II.cwc + group + Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit.cwc +      (1 + Bildung.II + Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit | SERIAL) +  
    (1 | day)
   Data: Daten

REML criterion at convergence: 1487.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1012 -0.4779  0.1252  0.5978  2.2565 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr       
 SERIAL   (Intercept)                  1.3071156 1.14329             
          Bildung.II                   0.0110698 0.10521  -1.00      
          Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit 0.0529128 0.23003  -0.84  0.84
 day      (Intercept)                  0.0001837 0.01355             
 Residual                              0.5300426 0.72804             
Number of obs: 611, groups:  SERIAL, 72; day, 10

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                       3.80037    0.18823  20.190
Bildung.II.cwc                    0.03092    0.04714   0.656
group                            -0.07622    0.11727  -0.650
Zeigen.Verhalten.Haeufigkeit.cwc  0.37383    0.05181   7.216

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Bl.II. group 
Bldng.II.cw -0.069              
group       -0.948  0.008       
Zgn.Vrhl.H. -0.007 -0.100 -0.005
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

The problem is that I need a results table containing residual variance at day and person-level (including standard errors) and I can't get these values from the table or via using code I found on the internet.

Comment: By standard errors do you mean the standard errors (i.e., uncertainty) of the variance estimates?  And, can you say more clearly what you mean by "residual variance at the person level" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
I was told to report those residual variances. I guess this refers to the remaining (not explained by the model) variance, that can be traced back to either the day-level (level 1 in the multilevel analysis) or the person-level (level 2).

Does that help?